# How to get the new Position of TMapView Markerposition in Delphi for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, maps

I Drop a marker with a long press on the TMapView in the APP. The position is right. But if i drag the marker and drop it elsewhere on the TMapView i got the old position of the marker.

Here my Testcode to get the new position in MapView1MarkerDragEnd(Marker: TMapMarker);
`showmessage(floattostr(fmarkers.Items[Fmarkers.Count- 1].Descriptor.Position.Latitude)+' '+floattostr(fmarkers.Items[Fmarkers.Count-1].Descriptor.Position.Longitude));`

or

```
showmessage(floattostr(marker.Descriptor.Position.Latitude)+' '+floattostr(marker.Descriptor.Position.Longitude));
```

Always the old marker position is shown. 
**How can i get the new position after Drag?**

here is my code to make a new marker:

```
MyMarker := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(marker.Descriptor.Position, '*temp*');
MyMarker.Draggable := True;
MyMarker.Visible :=True;
Fmarkers.Add(MapView1.AddMarker(MyMarker));
```

Comment: has no one a idea?

Comment: I have the same Problem. I tried using the MarkerDrag and MarkerDragEnd events but none of them gets the correct latitude and longitude of the marker.